# Delegate after subclassing?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, delegation

*I'm sorry, i was not able to formulate a short question for the title..*

In case i subclass a class with a delegate protocol and property, does my delegate still need to implement the delegate protocol of the superclass, or do i have to define a new one for the subclass?

In my case I subclassed `UIImagePickerController`:

```
[(UIImagePickerController *)self.myUIImagePickerControllerSubclassInstance setDelegate:self];
```

When I try to set its delegate to `self`, from some view controller I get the following warning:

> warning: Semantic Issue: Sending 'ViewController *' to parameter of
>   incompatible type
>   'id'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your delegate needs to comply with `UIImagePickerController` property declaration:

`@property (nonatomic, assign) id<UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate> delegate`

So, try adding `<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>` to your subclass interface:

```
@interface YourPicker : UIImagePickerController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
...
@end
```

And probably you'll need `UINavigationControllerDelegate` and implement mandatory methods, if any.

Comment: Thank You! I found out, that just adding UINavigationControllerDelegate to my viewController did it:`@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your delegate must also be compatible with the superclass. For example:

```
@protocol MyWebViewDelegate<UIWebViewDelegate>
{
     @optional
     -(void) myOptionalMethod1;
     -(void) myOptionalMethod2;

     @required
     -(void) myRequiredMethod1;
     -(void) myRequiredMethod2;
}
```

This protocol extends the web view delegate, so the two are compatible with each other.

Comment: Thanks You! So these are additional delegate methods my subclass adds to the existing ones from the superclass, right?