# Delegate declaration in subclass incompatible with delegate in parent class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a Timer class and a ManualTimer class, both of which declare a protocol. In Timer.h, I have this

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <TimerDelegate> delegate;
```

In ManualTimer.h, I have this

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) id <ManualTimerDelegate> delegate;
```

but xCode gives me a warning that

`property type id <ManualTimerDelegate> is incompatible with type id <TimerDelegate> inherited from parent class`

Indeed, one of the answers at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389142/delegate-after-subclassing) SO question says that the subclass delegate must be compatible with the superclass but it doesn't say how I can do that.  can you explain?
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Rename them could be a quick solution.

Comment: @Larme I tried this and it didn't work `@property (weak, nonatomic) id <ManualTimerDelegate> subclassdelegate;`

Comment: @larme well hold on, I think xCode's buggy, removed the whole delegate and warning's still there. You might have been right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare the `ManualTimerDelegate` protocol, have it conform to the "superclass" protocol (`TimerDelegate`).

```
@protocol ManualTimerDelegate < TimerDelegate >

@end
```

Your `TimerDelegate` should be something like this:

```
@protocol TimerDelegate < NSObject >

@end
```