# objective-c: delegate after sub-classing

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, delegation, gmsmapview

Well, i try to explain my problem:

1. I sub-classed MyMapView from GMSMapView

   `@interface MyMapView : GMSMapView
   @end`
2. Now i use MyMapView in MyViewController.m to show up a GMSMap and setup the delegate GMSMapViewDelegate.

   `@implementation MyViewController
      IBOutlet MyMapView *mapView;
   }`

   `-(void)viewDidLoad
   {
      [super viewDidLoad];
      GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.86
                                                         longitude:151.20
                                                              zoom:6];
      mapView = [MyMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
      self.view = mapView;
      mapView.delegate = self;
   }`
3. In MyViewController.h i declared the GMSMapViewDelegate

   `@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <GMSMapViewDelegate>
   @end`

Now i want to use some GMSMapViewDelegate-Methods in MyViewController but all i tried went wrong. Can anyone explain me how to use the GMSMapViewDelegate-Methods in this scenario?

Thanks, grethi.

Comment: I may have found a solution here [delegate-after-subclassing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389142/delegate-after-subclassing). After I tried it I will give feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i solved the problem by adding the delegate to the subclass AND to the view controller

```
@interface MyMapView : GMSMapView <GMSMapViewDelegate>
@end

@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <GMSMapViewDelegate>
@end
```

After this you can use the delegate-methods in the view controller.